# ASP.NET Authentication SetAuthCookie parameter

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP.NET web application, instead of redirecting to the original request URL as in following:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("user", false);
```

I want to redirect to a certain page, as follows:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( "SomeString", false);
Response.Redirect("MyPage.aspx", true);
```

What should be the value of the 1st parameter ("SomeString") to method SetAuthCookie() so that it would have the same effect as the above case of .RedirectFromLoginPage()?

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing the wheel, is there a particular reason?

Comment: I think he need to always redirect the user to "MyPage.aspx" instead of the "Returnurl". Perhaps some internal details of his application need that.

Comment: @m.Edmondson I don't understand what you see in my question that has been done already?

Comment: @DadyFuji  you are correct. The application needs to be redirected to a page defined in a configuration file.  The above code (that I wrote) works even with the value "SomeString". But I think it should be something different.  My guess is that .RedirectFromLoginPage() calls .SetAuthCookie implicitly passing it some value. And I would like to know what such value should be.

Comment: The user is already authenticated?  Therefore I'm not sure why you're setting a cookie at all? As you say the cookie is already set from `.RedirectFromLoginPage()` therefore the browser will automatically serve it for each request.

Comment: @m.Edmondson  No. The user is not authenticated until a method of the FormAuthentication class is called.

Comment: MSDN seems to think the user is already authenticated `Redirects an authenticated user` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f5z1yty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @m.Edmondson  You see I do not want to call the RedirectFromLoginPage but to redirect to my custom page. So I would need to call the method SetAuthCookie before Response.Redirect().

Answer (score 1):

The name of the authenticated user, according to MSDN [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk50ykcd(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk50ykcd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). the result will be the same.

Comment: DadyFuji.  So if understand the MSDN and your input correctly it does not really matter what name I pass.  When user logs out of the app the cookie is deleted.  Thank you.